# Escape metacharacters and using it as string variable for selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

eg.

I have var `myid="abc xyz"`

then I escape metachars using function and get `var x = "#"+escapechars(myid);`
which evaluate to `#abc\\xyz`

Now when I try to do `$(x)` it doesn't get any element
but when I type `$("#abc\\xyz")` in watch it gets the element.
I am attaching a screenshot for same scenario.

Problem is : I want to select the element using variable

Thank you.[image]

Here is the jsfiddle for my scenario.
http://jsfiddle.net/9hq4nzvx/3/

Comment: can you show us your code how you are evaluating ?

Comment: Can you post a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: check out this fiddle, you must be doing something else wrong => http://jsfiddle.net/9hq4nzvx/

Comment: added jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9hq4nzvx/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This >http://jsfiddle.net/9hq4nzvx/5/ solves the issue.

When we are using string variable that time we only need a single backslash instead of 2.

function escapechars now returns : "#abc\ xyz" which gets the element as needed.

```
var selection ="abc xyz";//this can be anything else comes from an array.
var x = "#"+escapeStr(selection); //"#abc\\\\\ xyz";

$(x).html("<h1>Hii</h1>");//why don't I get element here?
console.log(x);
alert(x);

$("#abc\\ xyz").append("<h2>bye</h2>");

function escapeStr(str) {//escape special chars from selectors
    if (str)
    return str.replace(/([ !"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~])/g, '\\$1');
    return str;
}
```